# Rails I18n Pluralization Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I wanted to set a custom error message for when an email was already taken so I edited the `config/locales/en.yml` file. It looked like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
        email:
          taken: "already being used"
```

When I submit the form with email in it, I get this error:

```
translation data {:email=>{:taken=>"already being used"}} can not be used with :count => 1
```

I've only just started looking into i18n so this may be a really simple mistake but I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: "already being used"
```

See section [5.1.1 in Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Hope this helps!